# SCIP compile error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, cmake, scip

I am trying to install SCIP, the MILP optimization software using cmake. First, I downloaded the SCIP Optimization Suite from [here](http://scip.zib.de/#download), then following the [instructions](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/CMAKE.php), I started by using cmake to build SoPlex (which it indicates that SCIP depends on). I pointed it to the appropriate directory then attempted to build SCIP. Cmake did not throw any errors, but when it came time to "make" it, it got ~60% of the way through then threw the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/scip
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_free_history_entry", referenced from:
      _SCIPdialoghdlrAddHistory in dialog.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/scip] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scip/src/CMakeFiles/scip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did some googling around to diagnose this, but everything I found seemed to be regarding XCode, which I am not using?

*I am on a mac running 10.11.3

**I apologize for the--what I am sure is--flagrant abuse of terminology, but I am not at all familiar with all of this compiling stuff.

Comment: [They said](http://listserv.zib.de/pipermail/scip/2012-April/000932.html) you need `readline` library installed, or disable it using `-DREADLINE=false` option to `cmake`.

Comment: Hmm, cmake is supposed to detect whether readline is available... In general, deactivating single components/dependencies is a good approach.

Comment: It works flawlessly on our test mac. Are you trying to install SCIP within Sage? Within Sage, this is a known issue, and readline has to be disabled explicitly as @tsyvarev suggested.

Comment: @Tsyvarev @mattmilten `-DREADLINE=false` eliminated the error, and while it appeared that the build worked, when I run `make check` every single test fails. My end goal here is to get SCIP working with PySCIPOPT, and looking at the instillation instructions there I need a `lib` sub directory in the scip directory, but the instillation of SCIP does not create that, so I am wondering if that might be part of the problem.

Comment: You should always try to *install* the SCIP Opt Suite. For this, please run `make install`. PySCIPOpt should then find the library and the headers automatically. If you're missing the admin permissions, you need to specify an install directory for SCIP using -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem in the meantime? It might be useful for users who run into a similar issue.

Comment: No, I was not able to figure it out. In the meantime I was using a different (newer mac) and it worked just fine. I just came back to try to get it working on the other machine and I am getting the same error still :(